# Como implementar un Trigger para editar un carrito de ventas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, trigger

**- Contexto:**

> Trato de hacer un carrito de ventas en mi proyecto, usando una tabla
> venta y una tabla detalle venta, puedo realizar el registro de manera
> normal.

**- Mis Tablas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**- Mi Problema:**

> Al momento de editar la venta y querer añadir otro detalle venta este
> se agrega a la ultima venta, pero no a la que corresponde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**- Mis Triggers:**

> Para tratar de manejar la cosa trate de manejarlo con 2 triggers.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Gracias de Antemano.***

Comment: Entiendo que esto está más relacionado a una transacción que a un iniciador. Tu idea es agregar un registro en la tabla `venta` y, posteriormente, agregar los detalles oportunos en la tabla `venta_detalle`, ¿cierto? En ese caso, ¿para qué necesitas el iniciador? ¿vas a corregir TODAS las inserciones? Si alguna vez modificas una venta para agregar nuevos registros a la tabla `venta_detalle` estarás obligando a que esos detalles se agreguen a la última venta hecha, y no a la que deseas. ¿Sabes cómo obtener la `id` que ha sido generada automáticamente tras una inserción?

Comment: Yo veo que tu problema esta en los triggers al hacer un BEFORE INSERT haces la consulta a **SELECT id FROM venta ORDER BY lastmodified DESC** por lo que siempre editaras el ultimo, tendrías que leer el id de la venta antes de mostrarla y si se hacen cambios cargar esa data en base a esa id, pero omitiendo el trigger.

Comment: OscarGarcia, a que te refieres con una transacción?